# Матрица из нолей и единиц

Tags: c++

Матрица, состоящая из единиц и нулей. Нужно написать программу, которая найдет размер самой большой подматрицы в матрице, состоящей только из единиц. Работа с динамическим массивом. Пример:

```
1 0 0

1 1 1

0 1 1
```

Дает результат 2 (размер матрицы из единиц)
P.S. Нужно квадратную матрицу, код написан на cpp.sh

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int min(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int n;
    cin >>n;
    int **x = new int*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        *(x+i) = new int[n];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
        *(*(x+i)+j)=rand()%2;
        }
    }
    int x_currentmax; //для подсчета самой минимальной ширины
    int max; //самая большая подматрица в матрице
    int i_position=0, j_position=0; //для подсчета вперед вниз
    int i_count=0, j_count=0; //для подсчета размера
    int minmax;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        i_position = i;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            x_currentmax =0;
            y_currentmax = 0;
            j_position = j;
            if(*(*(x+i)+j) == 1)
            {
                while(*(*(x+i_position)+j_position) == 1)
                {
                    while(*(*(x+i_position)+j_position+1) == 1 && j_position+1 <n)
                    {
                        j_position++;
                        j_count++;
                    }
                    if(j_count > x_currentmax)
                        x_currentmax = j_count;
                    else if(j_count < x_currentmax)
                        x_currentmax = j_count;
                    while(*(*(x+i_position+1)+j_position) == 1 && i_position+1 <n)
                    {
                        i_position++;
                        i_count++;
                    }
                    minmax=min(x_currentmax,i_count);

                }
                if(minmax>max)
                    max=minmax;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
    cout << *(*(x+i)+j) << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
    cout << max;
}

int min(int x, int y)
{
    if(x>y)
        return y;
    else
        return x;
}
```

Comment: И что вам мешает написать такую программу? Раз уж нужно?

Comment: пробовал но не получилось, могу скинуть код, но она неработеат

Comment: Самой большой квадратной подматрицы? Если нет, то как считается размер?

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко, я бы предположил, что прямоугольной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все уже решил, вот если кому-то пригодиться

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int n,i,j,z=0;
    bool g;
    cin >>n;
    int **x = new int*[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        *(x+i) = new int[n];
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
        *(*(x+i)+j)=rand()%2;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            cout<<*(*(x+i)+j)<<'\t';
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++) //предпалагаемый размер подматрицы
    {
        for(j=0; j<=n-i; j++)  //строки
        {
            for(int k=0; k<=n-i; k++) //столбцы
            {
                for(int h=j;h<j+i;h++)  //строки
                    for(int p=k;p<k+i;p++)  //столбцы
                        if(x[h][p]!=1)
                            g=false;
                if(g==true)  
                    z=i;
                g=true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(z!=0)
        cout<<z<<endl;
    else cout<<"Нету";

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Вам наверно нужны анаграммы

```
#include <map>

string s;
map <char, int> m;
cin >> s;
int l = s.size(), count = 1;
long long fact[15];
fact[1] = 1;
for (int i = 2; i <= l; i++) //заполняем массив факториалов
fact[i] = fact[i - 1] * i;
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) //подчитываем повторения
    ++m[s[i]];
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
if (it->second > 1) count *= fact[it->second];
cout << fact[l] / count << "\n" << endl;
```

Анаграммой слова называется любая перестановка всех букв слова.Например, из слова 
SOLO можно получить 12 анаграмм: 
SOLO, LOSO, OSLO, OLSO, OSOL, OLOS, SLOO, LSOO, OOLS, OOSL, LOOS, SOOL.

Так же можно получить ангиограммы ваших нулей и единиц

Comment: Как применить анаграммы к вопросу, заданному топикстартером?

Comment: Сразу скажу что это не мой код я его с интернета взял и он убогий, уверен что если смысл поймете сможете сделать более компактным.

Comment: @AK Обычно новички часто путают матрицу с анаграммами вот и скинул.
Все может быть точно не понятно какая матрица нужна.

Comment: Сам вопрос непонятен, можно искать и квадратную матрицу и прямоугольные. Я прикрыл пока вопрос, возможно, автор приложит усилия, чтобы прояснить его.

Comment: @AK Может ему все варианты нужны :)

Comment: @AK да простите забыл написать что нужны только квадратные матрицы, но анаграмм не надо было :Д

Comment: @Yanun Если вы поправили вопрос - вам можно под вопросом нажать кнопку "переоткрыть", чтобы участники смогли проверить поправленный вопрос и проголосовать за/против переоткрытия. Я бы ещё добавил в вопрос перед тем как переоткрывать - уточнить, что вам нужно - код или алгоритм. Также, глядишь и минусы с вопроса кто-то снимет, если вы приложите свои попытки решить задачу. Вы же пишете "есть код" - приклыдывайте, пусть будут видно, как вы думали над задачей. А то у нас на сайте многие не одобряют помощь в решении домашней работы и это есть и в правилах сайта.

Comment: @AK не вижу кнопку переоткрыть